# How to fix template does not exist error on production server using django?

Tags: python, django, templates, settings, production

**UPDATE: See self-answer. I failed to restart apache when i made the changes.**

When I try to run my django app in a production server, I’m getting the following error with regards to finding the template.  I believe it’s something to do with the location of where the template is stored; I’ve changed the directory in my settings file but I’m thinking I might have missed another place.

I'm trying to find where I have "C:/django/booking/reserve" referenced since this is the path given but I can't seem to figure out where.  Any advice?

```
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    reserve/templates/index.html
Exception Location: /home/sharataka/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 138
Python Path:    ['/home/sharataka/webapps/django',
 '/home/sharataka/webapps/django/booking',
 '/home/sharataka/webapps/django/reserve',
 '/home/sharataka/webapps/django/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/sharataka/lib/python2.7/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/sharataka/lib/python2.7/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/sharataka/lib/python2.7/django_debug_toolbar-0.9.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/sharataka/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
•   Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
o   /home/sharataka/C:/django/booking/reserve/templates/index.html (File does not exist
```

## settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)


STATIC_ROOT = '/webapps/django/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    "/webapps/django",
)
```

Comment: Is that a copy-paste issue or is it really a concatenated path of:  `/home/sharataka/C:/django/booking/reserve/templates/index.html` ?  Also, do you have the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` variable set in your settings?

Comment: @jdi not sure what you mean by copy-paste issue, but I've included what I have in template_dirs.  I am trying to figure out where else the path "C:/django/booking/reserve" could be referenced in my files since that's what I'm seeing in the errors when it tries to load the template.

Comment: But I don't see a `C:/django/booking/reserve`. I see `/home/sharataka/C:/django/booking/reserve/templates/index.html`. What is the separator? That looks like one path.

Comment: I guess that's my question...where did that "C:/django/booking/reserve" come from and how did it get included in the /home/sharataka... path?  What do you mean by separator?

Comment: There isn't enough here to know where its coming from really. But yes, its showing you one path. What I mean by separator is that the path its looking at does not start with `C:/`. It starts with your `/home/`. Somehow...somewhere...its concatenating your windows path with your linux homedir.

Comment: Any ideas on where I can start to look?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15743/discussion-between-sharataka-and-jdi)

Comment: Just make a text in files search for "C:/django/booking/reserve/templates/index.html" or ""C:/django/booking/reserve/" or similiar. It must be somewhere defined in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I failed to restart apache when i made the changes... I'm a django rookie :)